# Long equation, and the equation number, does not fit into 1 column!

Tags: equations, formatting, multicolumn

I have a 2 columns LaTeX document (in overleaf). I want to add a formula in one of the columns.

My current code looks like this:

```
\[0.39\frac{total\_word\_count}{total\_sentence\_count} + 
11.8\frac{total\_syllable\_count}{total\_word\_count}\tag{1}\]
```

And produces the following equation (in the right column, which is where I want it):

[image]

I showed some text above and below to give an impression of how it looks in the text.

Ideally I want it to look like:

EQUATION    (1)

short description

I tried using the `\begin{equation}` field with `resizebox`, but did not succeed.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How about defining some variables inside your text instead: `... where $w$ represents the total word count, $s$ the total sentence count and $y$ the total syllable count. ...` That way you can just use the letters in your formulae.

Comment: you should use `\texrm{total\_word\_count}` that may be enough to make it smaller, or  `\texrm{\small total\_word\_count}`  but as you have provided no test document it is hard to test answers as for example we do not know the column width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By use of the `\mfrac` instruction defined in the `nccmath` package:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{equation}
0.39\mfrac{\textrm{total\_word\_count}}{\textrm{total\_sentence\_count}} {+}
11.8\mfrac{\textrm{total\_syllable\_count}}{\textrm{total\_word\_count}}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[1][4-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Various possibilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

dont use math italic (or number by hand)
\begin{equation}
0.39\frac{total\_word\_count}{total\_sentence\_count} + 
11.8\frac{total\_syllable\_count}{total\_word\_count}
\end{equation}



scriptstyle
\begin{equation}\scriptstyle
0.39\tfrac{\textrm{total\_word\_count}}{\textrm{total\_sentence\_count}} {+} 
11.8\tfrac{\textrm{total\_syllable\_count}}{\textrm{total\_word\_count}}
\end{equation}

two lines
\begin{multline}
0.39\frac{\textrm{total\_word\_count}}{\textrm{total\_sentence\_count}} \\
+ 11.8\frac{\textrm{total\_syllable\_count}}{\textrm{total\_word\_count}}
\end{multline}

shorter names
\begin{equation}
0.39\frac{\textrm{tword}}{\textrm{tsentence}} + 
11.8\frac{\textrm{tsyllable}}{\textrm{tword}}
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```